# ios/Best practice for filtering tables - one view controller or many

Tags: ios, objective-c

IOS newb coming from a PHP/MYSQL background.

I have two page views that are quite similar, differing only in a query parameter that returns a different set of records.  Since the records are different, I also want to give the pages different title.  This issue comes up multiple times in my project but one example would be one page is designed to return mail sent and the other mail received.

The data is coming from a server on the backend through a json web service.

For a website using PHP/MYSQL, I would be strongly inclined to have one page and just return a different title and records based on a query parameter.

Question:

In Xcode/IOS should I use one table view controller for this page or separate table view controllers.

I am leaning toward two as the two pages occupy different places in the navigation hierarchy.  However, the pages are really quite similar except for the title and what they show and separate view controllers seems to go against the principal of not repeating code.

Thanks for any suggestions.  Apologies my question does not include code example..it's more understanding best practices for how IOS should work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the way you've posed your question is that in your head you do not appear to be doing object-oriented programming. Distinguish, please, between "different view controllers" and "different view controller *classes*". If these pieces of interface occupy different places in the interface, or even the same place but one transitions to / is replaced by another, they *must* be different view controllers. But they can certainly be instances of the same view controller *class* (or, of subclasses of the same view controller class), and probably should be.

Comment: See, for example, my Albumen app (free, just download it and take a look). It has three interfaces - for displaying your albums, your audio books, and your podcasts. Very similar to your same data differently filtered. That's three instances of one view controller class.

Comment: so maybe subclass table view controller with a class that has all the necessary code to pull and display the table and then create different instances of it?

Comment: _Exactly._ What you've just said is precisely standard operating procedure in iOS programming. In Albumen, it is just what I do; the behavior of the different instances is _slightly_ different so I have a "type" instance variable and those differences depend on switching on that.

Comment: I was loose with the terminology.  When I said view controllers, I meant in Storyboard.  But I gather they can be instances of the same class.  So when I connect the storyboard view controller to a class in the identity inspector, I can reference the same one.  And yes it is hard to think in OO.  I guess 1 million apps can't be wrong but it seems much harder than web programming.

Comment: Correct again. Now you're cooking with gas.

Comment: One more hint, in line what you've already suggested. Some Cocoa classes are _intended_ for subclassing. No one would _ever_ use a UITableViewController plain and simple; you will _always_ subclass it, since otherwise you can't customize its functionality. Now the question is whether to reuse that same subclass or split it off into further subclasses or what. I'm suggesting there's no need to go that far, because this is basically repeated functionality in both places.

Comment: On OO you might want to read my book starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch02.html